# RabbitMQ : Can I get latest n messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, messagebroker

I'm new on RabbitMQ.

I implemented websocket server with `tyrus` to get messages on real-time like Push Server with the book [RabbitMQ essentials](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/rabbitmq-essentials).

however, When I disconnected and reconnect, the server send all messages
because I implemented like this.

```
consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel)
{
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(final String consumerTag,
                   final Envelope envelope,
                   final BasicProperties properties,
                   final byte[] body) throws IOException
    {
    handler.handleDelivery(channel, envelope, properties, body);
    }

};
```

So, I want to get 20 latest messages when users have requested(like scrolling),
however, in honestly, I can't imagine how to implement it.

I want to implement these things.

1. When a user connected to websocket server, then server sends latest 20 messages.
2. When a user opened inbox layout and reached scroll bottom, then server sends next 20 messages.
3. A new message for this user while has connected, 
   then server send on real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use prefetch count to limit consuming of unacknowledged messages at your consumer startup.

You can use basicQos method on your channel. 
From RabbitMQ docs:

```
Channel channel = ...;
Consumer consumer = ...;
channel.basicQos(20); // Per consumer limit
channel.basicConsume("my-queue", false, consumer);
```

Refer RabbitMQ docs for more detail: http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

Comment: thanks to your answer Agarwal. But queue messages will consumed from first message, right? If I want to consume from latest message, then how can I do for it?

Comment: If I understands correctly, you need LIFO behavior QUEUE. I am afraid, AMQP as such doesn't provide such implementation: http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/LIFO-queue-td18860.html